# Fine tuning transition delays - CSS

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, transition

I'm working on a website with a left navigation bar and I need some help fine-tuning the transition delays. Here's the website: http://104.193.173.104/modx/index.php

**Desktop**

- Starts wide (240px) with social icons inline
- Click hamburger to shrink (56px wide) and social icons stack

**Tablet**

- Starts narrow (56px) with social icons stacked
- Click hamburger to open (240px) and social icons go inline

The problem is that when I switch from narrow to wide, the icons stack first, bump the below navigation down, and then open up to inline. The goal is to have the lower set of navigation stay in the same vertical position through the whole change. I'm assuming I need to use the transition-delay css property, but I'm not very familiar with it and struggling to get things to work.

.mmc means Main Menu Collapse and .mme is Expand.

**Code:**

```css
@media (max-width: 480px) {
      #social-links-container {
        padding: 60px 0;
      }
      ul.social-links {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style-type: none;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
      .social-links li {
        display: inline;
        padding: 0 18px;
      }
      .social-links li a {
        min-width: 80px;
        color: #808b9c;
      }
    }
    
    /* tablet */
    @media (min-width: 480px) {
      #social-links-container {
        padding: 45px 0 20px;
      }
      .mme #social-links-container {
        padding: 60px 0;
      }
      ul.social-links {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style-type: none;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
      .social-links li {
        display: block;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 15px;
      }
      .mme .social-links li {
        display: inline;
        padding: 0 18px;
      }
      .social-links li a {
        min-width: 80px;
        color: #808b9c;
      }
    }
    
    /* desktop */
    @media (min-width: 992px) {
      #social-links-container {
        padding: 60px 0;
      }
      .mmc #social-links-container {
        padding: 45px 0 20px;
      }
      ul.social-links {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style-type: none;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
      .social-links li {
        display: inline;
        padding: 0 18px;
      }
      .mmc .social-links li {
        display: block;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 15px;
      }
      .social-links li a {
        min-width: 80px;
        color: #808b9c;
      }
    }
```

```html
<div id="main-menu" role="navigation">
     <div id="main-menu-inner">
    
         <!-- LOGOS -->
         <div id="logo">
             <a href="index.php">
        <img src="/modx/assets/images/logos/ComoxCaptivates_blue_220.png">
       </a>
         </div>
    
         <div id="logo-collapsed" >
             <a href="index.php">
                 <img src="/modx/assets/images/logos/32x32.png">
             </a>
         </div>
         
         <!-- SOCIAL MEDIA -->
         <div id="social-links-container">
             <ul class="social-links">
                 <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/TownofComox/"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official fa-2x fa-fw"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/TownofComox"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x fa-fw"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="[[~#]]"><i class="fa fa-calendar fa-2x fa-fw"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    
         <!-- LEFT NAVIGATION -->
         <ul class="navigation">
             <li>
                 <a href="[[~9]]">
                     <i class="fa fa-bicycle fa-lg fa-fw" style="margin-right: 8px;"></i>
                     <span class="mm-text">Recreation</span>
                 </a>
             </li>
             <li>
                 <a href="[[~10]]">
                     <i class="fa fa-users fa-lg fa-fw" style="margin-right: 8px;"></i>
                     <span class="mm-text">Employment</span>
                 </a>
             </li>
             <li>
                 <a href="[[~11]]">
                     <i class="fa fa-map-o fa-lg fa-fw" style="margin-right: 8px;"></i>
                     <span class="mm-text">Maps</span>
                 </a>
             </li>
             <li>
                 <a href="[[~12]]">
                     <i class="fa fa-tint fa-lg fa-fw" style="margin-right: 8px;"></i>
                        <span class="mm-text">Water Restrictions</span>
                 </a>
             </li>
             <li>
                 <a href="[[~13]]">
                     <i class="fa fa-ship fa-lg fa-fw" style="margin-right: 8px;"></i>
                        <span class="mm-text">Tourism</span>
                 </a>
             </li>
             <li>
                 <a href="[[~14]]">
                     <i class="fa fa-money fa-lg fa-fw" style="margin-right: 8px;"></i>
                        <span class="mm-text">Investment</span>
                 </a>
             </li>
         </ul>     
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The `mmc` class disappears at the moment you click the nav button. What you could do, is remove the class when the navbar finish the transition, not when it is starting it. Could you show us the javascript code of that?

Comment: Thanks, @azeós! I'm using the PixelAdmin theme and not very good with javascript. I searched through the **huge** file and came up with this function: https://jsfiddle.net/99sueoLd/ 

Is that the right one?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be that piece of code. But I don't thinks it's gonna be easy to change it. Let me think on a CSS solution.

Comment: @azeós Hahaha my thoughts exactly! This JS file is 1.4MB :( I appreciate your help!